# PyCharm Nosetests run instead of run

Tags: python, pycharm, nose

I want to run from `PyCharm` my python `foo.py`, just a normal run.

Yet often I see (specifically when I add a new file) only option to run `Nosetests in foo.py` which I do not install, have no idea what it is and do not want.

I want my simple `run` back (like I have available for other python files in PyCharm in this project and this file may be run from a console, so I do not get why PyCharm insists on this `nosetests`). And it fails due to some modules missing.

So I want this (under right click) like I have for my other .py files in the project:

[image]

But I get this:

[image]

It seems to start few months back after some update.

Do you know how to put back my normal `run` instead of nosetests?